# Cliques in $k$-partite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Recall that a *$k$-partite graph* is a graph whose vertices are or can be partitioned into k different independent sets and that a *clique* of a graph is subset of the vertices such that every two distinct vertices are adjacent.

Suppose that the clique number of a graph $G$ is $ω(G)=k$ and that every vertex of $G$ belongs to a clique of size $k$. Does this imply that the graph $G$ is $k$-partite? If not, what additional conditions would guarantee this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Does this imply that the graph G is k-partite?" No. The simplest example is an odd cycle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian for examples of graphs with clique size 3 and large chromatic number.

The condition that every vertex belongs to a clique of size $k$ is not relevant as dummy vertices can be added to form such cliques.

"If not, what additional conditions would guarantee this property?"
Perfect graphs such as bipartite graphs, chordal graphs etc. satisfy this property.

Comment: Thanks Aravind for your reply! What is the exact implication then? Maybe "$G$ perfect graph and $ω(G)=k$ implies $G$ $k$-partite"? The way to prove this is simply seeing $G$ as (trivial) induced subgraph of itself, right? Does the fact that every vertex belongs to a clique of size $k$ become a consequence?

Comment: That's right, for every subgraph of a perfect graph G, chromatic number and clique number are equal, in particular this is true for G. Every vertex belonging to a clique of size k doesn't become a consequence; you mentioned that as a property satisfied by G, and as I pointed out, it doesn't affect the chromatic number directly.